# how to trigger an event in controller2 based on an action in controller1

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/MwZB3OLJj04qBawSFYyF) is the plunkr i have created.
Basically i am facing 2 issues with this piece of code -

1. I need help loading months in the drop down and
2. When month is changed in the dropdown from `headerController`, the sales for that month is displayed in `detailController`. I am trying to create a dependency between multiple controllers using a `service`.

I will appreciate any help fixing these 2 issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply achieve this by using `$broadcast` from one controller in `$rootScope` and listen that event in `$scope` using `$on`. Though I would suggest you to use service that will share data among to controller. Using dot rule will reduce your code. Take a look at below optimized code. Also you could replace your `select` with `ng-repeat` with `ng-option` to save object on select.

**Markup**

```
  <div data-ng-controller="headerController">
    <h3>Select Month</h3>
    <select id="month" ng-model="sales.selectedMonth" 
     ng-options="month.monthId for month in sales.monthlySales">
    </select>
  </div>
  <div data-ng-controller="detailsController">
    <h3>Sales for  Month</h3>
    <div ng-bind="sales.selectedMonth"></div>
  </div>
```

**Code**

```
app.service('valuesService', [function() {
  var factory = {};
  factory.sales = {}
  factory.sales.salesForMonthId = 10;
  factory.sales.months = [1, 2];

  factory.sales.monthlySales = [{monthId: 1,sales: 10}, {monthId: 2,sales: 20}];
  factory.sales.selectedMonth = factory.sales.monthlySales[0];
  return factory;
}]);

app.controller('headerController', ['$scope', 'valuesService',
  function($scope, valuesService) {
    $scope.sales = {};
    getData();
    function getData() {
      $scope.sales = valuesService.sales;
    }
  }
]);

app.controller('detailsController', ['$scope', 'valuesService',
  function($scope, valuesService) {
    $scope.sales = {};
    getData();
    function getData() {
      $scope.sales = valuesService.sales;
    }
  }
]);
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/Bzi1BrRPN1pvQzPAqJGA?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

You can use $broadcast service for event purposes. Following is the link which explains the use of $broadcast and communicating between two controllers.

`enter code here`http://plnkr.co/edit/d98mOuVvFMr1YtgRr9hq?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I can see the months are already loading fine.

For proper data binding to work across service and controller, you would need to bind one level above the actual data, resulting a dot in your expression. This is because javascript doesn't pass by reference for primitive type.

In service:

```
factory.data = {
  salesForMonthId: 0
}
```

In controller:

```
app.controller('detailsController', ['$scope', 'valuesService',
  function ($scope, valuesService) {
      $scope.values = valuesService.data;
  }
]);
```

In template:

```
<div>{{values.salesForMonthId}}</div>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TP2uTwXFhpgxzsFGhYbP?p=preview)